# How to Edit a MySQL Data base from a PHP Site

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have built a database named "artStore" and a table within that database named "inventory". I've been able to figure out how to create a new entry to the database, but I'm trying to create a page that can edit those entries.

Here is "inventory" the table I created:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE inventory (
  id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product VARCHAR(30),
  category VARCHAR(30),
  seller VARCHAR(30)
  )";
```

Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
<?php 
    $resultProduct = "product";
    $resultCategory = "category";
    $resultSeller = "seller";

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultProduct = $row["product"];
        $resultCategory = $row["category"];
        $resultSeller = $row["seller"];
      }
    } else {
      echo "No Results";
    }
     ?>
    <form action="update.php" method="POST">

      <label for="product">Product</label>
      <input id="product" type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $resultProduct; ?>">
      <br>

      <label for="category">Category:</label>
      <input id="category" type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $resultCategory; ?>">
      <br>

      <label for="seller">Seller:</label>
      <input id="seller" type="text" name="seller" value="<?php echo $resultSeller; ?>">
      <br>

      <input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultId; ?>" style="display:none;">
      <input type="submit" value="Update My Record">
    </form>
```

What I'm trying in update.php

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$seller = $_POST['seller'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (product, category, seller) VALUES ('$product', '$category', '$seller')";

if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
  echo "Inserted Successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error occured in the insert: " . $connection->error;
}


 $connection->close();
```

Comment: Yes you do need to post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Any basic PHP/mySQL tutorial will address this.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Instead of wasting your time posting that, you could have moved on. Tutorials address half the things people post on this site. Obviously if the tutorials worked for me, I wouldn't be here. So what's your point?

Comment: Code looks fine. Make sure you are defining the `$resultId` variable and run the update query on submit based on that id.

Comment: @Aditya How do I go about doing that?

Comment: My point is that if I enter the title of your question into Google, I get dozens of results describing how to do this. Trying any of those solutions would enable you to solve this issue yourself, or at least ask a more pointed question. As it stands, your question is 1) too broad, and 2) shows insufficient research effort.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen So what if I tried the tutorials and they aren't working for me? Thats the point of this site. I clearly tried something and don't know why its not working. And how is it too broad when I have my code up there? I'm just asking how to get it to work..?

Comment: @Kira Can you please post the code in update.php also so that we can see the update query and help you out

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen And why are you wasting both of our time if you don't have an answer? I'm pretty sure the site isn't for just putting your two cents everywhere.

Comment: @Veerendra Edit 2, updated to show what I'm trying in update.php

Comment: @Kira I have posted the answer according to the update.php and now one action file can perform insert and update for you 
Please accept the answer if it help you

Comment: @Veerendra I know, I've seen. I'm working on it, still trying to get it to work.

Comment: @kira: then you should at least clearly explain **HOW** this code isn't working for you. If there's no obvious syntax/structural errors in the code, then there's literally nothing we can do to help you, because we have **NO** idea what's wrong. maybe the database is down. maybe you're talking to the wrong database, maybe you made a typo and you're submitting the form to the wrong script. **NONE** Of that is something we can figure out from what you've posted.

Comment: @Kira Have you heard of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @worldofjr yes but I need to be able to edit the table from the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code I added hidden field on form and changes on your sql query

```
<?php 
        $resultProduct = "product";
        $resultCategory = "category";
        $resultSeller = "seller";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultProduct = $row["product"];
            $resultCategory = $row["category"];
            $resultSeller = $row["seller"];
            $resultId = $row["id"];
          }
        } else {
          echo "No Results";
        }
         ?>
        <form action="update.php" method="POST">
     <input  type="text" name="update_id" value="<?php echo $resultId; ?>">
          <label for="product">Product</label>
          <input id="product" type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $resultProduct; ?>">
          <br>

          <label for="category">Category:</label>
          <input id="category" type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $resultCategory; ?>">
          <br>

          <label for="seller">Seller:</label>
          <input id="seller" type="text" name="seller" value="<?php echo $resultSeller; ?>">
          <br>

          <input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultId; ?>" style="display:none;">
          <input type="submit" value="Update My Record">
        </form>
```

In update.php

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$seller = $_POST['seller'];
$updateId = $_POST['update_id'];

$sql = "UPDATE inventory set product = '$product',category='$category',seller='$seller' WHERE id = '$updateId'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
        $resultProduct = "product";
        $resultCategory = "category";
        $resultSeller = "seller";
        $resultId = "product_id";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultProduct = $row["product"];
            $resultCategory = $row["category"];
            $resultSeller = $row["seller"];
            $resultid = $row["id"];
          }
        } else {
          echo "No Results";
        }
     ?>
```

You were using `$resultId` in the form but you have not declared and assigned a value to it in the loop.

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
  <input id="id" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultId; ?>">
  <label for="product">Product</label>
  <input id="product" type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $resultProduct; ?>">
  <br>

  <label for="category">Category:</label>
  <input id="category" type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $resultCategory; ?>">
  <br>

  <label for="seller">Seller:</label>
  <input id="seller" type="text" name="seller" value="<?php echo $resultSeller; ?>">
  <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Update My Record">
</form>
<!-- Instead of passing the ID in textbox with display: none you can pass it directly in hidden -->

<?php

    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $seller = $_POST['seller'];
    $product_id = $_POST['id'];

    if($product_id!='')//MEANS WE HAVE TO UPDATE THE RECORD
    {
        // UPDATE QUERY WILL UPDATE THE SAME RECORD ONLY MATCHING THE UNIQUE PRODUCT ID
        $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET product = '$product', category = '$category', seller = '$seller' WHERE id = '$product_id' LIMIT 1";
        if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
          echo "Updated Successfully";
        } else {
          echo "Error occured in the insert: " . $connection->error;
        }
    }
    else// If id is blank it means you have a new record
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (product, category, seller) VALUES ('$product', '$category', '$seller')";
        if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
          echo "Inserted Successfully";
        } else {
          echo "Error occured in the insert: " . $connection->error;
        }
    }

    $connection->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure this out.. I changes my files to your exact code and now when I click my edit button, it takes me to the form which I can enter new things, but then it sends me to a blank screen?

Comment: @Kira Can you please add the select query above the form so i can get the exact issue as all the code should work so may be the issue is with the select query.

PLease inspect the form and see whether you are getting the value of resultId in  hidden or not